# ExtJS: Filter gridpanel, but not the store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Is it possible to filter a grid panel but leaving the store untouched ?

I need to be able to find a record in the store, so if a stored is filtered as I am hiding the information in my grid then I would be able to get a record from filterd store ?  If I clear the filter then the gridpanel would show items that I wanted hidden.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a snapshot property of store. It holds original store when you make some changes on store values.
This is the related [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-snapshot).

Answer (score -1):

No longer supported in 6.0,  may have already been removed in 5.0